# pygeoda - LISA for round polygon

Tags: python, geopandas, moran-index, geoda

I have just started to use pygeoda package and I have tried to calculate LISA .
I had originally raster which I polygonized to have polygon for each pixel:
[image]

I have applied MORAN I and LISA on the squared polygons, but it seems like it takes into account the null value white polygons around the "circle", so the result looks like this:

[image: ~~~]

This is how I got the result:

```
data=pygeoda.open('shape/vectorize1.shp')

rook_w = pygeoda.rook_weights(data, order=3, include_lower_order=False, precision_threshold = 0)

crm_lisa = pygeoda.local_moran(rook_w, data['VALUE'])


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,10))
lisa_colors = crm_lisa.lisa_colors()
lisa_labels = crm_lisa.lisa_labels()

# attach LISA cluster indicators to geodataframe
gdf['LISA'] = crm_lisa.lisa_clusters()

for ctype, data in gdf.groupby('LISA'):
    color = lisa_colors[ctype]
    lbl = lisa_labels[ctype]
    data.plot(color = color,
        ax = ax,
        label = lbl,
        edgecolor = 'black',
        linewidth = 0.2)
```

My goal is to calculate MORAN I and LISA only inside the not null values. Also, I haven't seen the MORAN I value itself, but that is not the main goal of this post.

Clarification: "the null value white polygons around the "circle"" - In order to calculate LISA I have taken raster image and polygonized it. The raster was clipped, so it has null values around the "circle". I want to calculate LISA only inside the circle, e.g the pixels with values, and to ignore the null values, but it seems like the calculation is also taking into account the null values around.

Comment: How do you polygonized? What tool do you use for polygonizing? Tool parameters? Is the raster PNG with alpha channel or JPG?

Comment: What is `VALUE` value for polygons in white area?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz the value there is Null , and I polygonized it in qgis

Comment: Why do you remove the polygons come from the white pixels before calculation?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz not sure I understood your question, but I wanted to get the calcualtion only for the pixels inside the plot

Comment: I guess I understand something wrong.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz can you please explain what you missunderstood? maybe I need to refine my question

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the null value white polygons around the "circle"". Which white polygons? All the polygons generated from white pixels? Or the white polygons within the blue polygons?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I have edited the post, I hope now is more clear

Comment: Could you share the polygon shapefile with NULL values? I polygonized the image above (no NULL values, used red channel), and run the script. Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4NiU.png. Meanwhile, I have no idea What MORAN I and LISA mean. I just run the script on the polygons I have. I just test the script and review the result.

Comment: It looks like you need a preprocessing step to remove the null value polygons from the shp.  After you polygonize the raster in QGIS, delete the null value polygons and save before opening in pygeoda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There do not appear to be any methods to filter data in pygeoda.  Therefore, you will need an additional preprocessing step to remove the polygons that you don't want to process.

In QGIS, after converting your raster to polygons, toggle editing on the new polygon layer.  Select all polygons with a value of NULL, and delete them.  Save your edits, then run the pygeoda script.

Answer (score 2):

You normally can drop NaN values from `gdf` and use it in pygeoda according to [documentation](https://geodacenter.github.io/pygeoda/load_data.html). I encountered an [issue](https://github.com/GeoDaCenter/pygeoda/issues/21) (reported as bug). So I tried the following way. It worked for me.

```
...

gdf = gpd.read_file('shape/vectorize1.shp')
gdf = gdf.dropna()
gdf.to_file('shape/vectorize2.shp')

gdf = gpd.read_file('shape/vectorize2.shp')
data = pygeoda.open('shape/vectorize2.shp')

...
```

Comment: it still does the same issue